# Magento Reflection Exception Error on application homepage

Tags: magento2

i recently just cloned a repo from github which is supposed to help me customize the magento city field on the checkout page. But i get the following error after installing the module. Package github repository https://github.com/EaDesgin/Magento2-City-Dropdown [image]

Comment: Try removing var/generated folder and flush cache.

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize `$citiesData` as array

```
$citiesData = [];
```

> add above code in **app/code/Eadesigndev/RomCity/Block/Checkout/Cities.php**

```
$citiesData = [];
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $citiesData[$item->getEntityId()] = $item;
}
```

> add above code in **app/code/Eadesigndev/RomCity/Helper/CitiesJsonRomCity.php**

```
$citiesData = [];
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $citiesData[$item->getEntityId()] = $item;
}
```

**Hope it Helps.**

Comment: I think this answer is not related to the question at all.

Comment: @AboElnouR I have checked this module in my system and also faced the same error as shown in the question and answered here accordingly.

Comment: The error is missing class, not a variable and for me the module working fine without those lines.